# how much time lapse should a couple be separated from each other to sustain nikkah between them?

Tags: nikah

If a married couple stay away from each other for a long duration with no contact between them, then would nikkah be still like a bound between them? Can they continue their relationship as husband n wife again? How much period should a couple stay away from each other to keep nikah between them?

If a couple dont do divorce or khula but they are separated from each other, so after a long interval do they have the right to stay with each other ?kindly answer with sharah reference

Comment: A marriage ends with death or divorce. After a long separation if one of the parties wants to initiate divorce they must try to find the other for a certain time, only after that a qadi can declare a legal separation.

Answer (score 1):

**There is nothing breaking nikah if the couple is not together for any period of time.**

If anyone says it breaks the nikah, he/she should produce shariah references for this. I don't think any reference is required to say that it does not break the nikah because there is no reference which might prove that it breaks nikah. So when something is not broken it's intact. So, nikah is fully valid.

### Allah knows best